# How do I take a dependency on a COM object without an interop assembly?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, com, shdocvw

When I add a reference (Common properties, framework and references, add new reference) to Microsoft internet controls/SHDocVw.dll and compile the project, a new file is created in the release folder of the project. The file (Interop.SHDocVw.1.1.dll) needs to be in the same folder as the program for it to run.

How do I make my program use the SHDocVw.dll located in system32 instead of the Interop.SHDocVw.1.1.dll in my programs folder?

Comment: Is that the very best title you could come up with?

Comment: Set the "Embed Interop Types" property of the assembly reference to True.  Hard to miss, it is True by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primary interop assembly is not used *instead of* the native DLL, it's a .NET binding layer that loads the native DLL.  The Windows DLL is still doing all the hard work.

Comment: So I must have the Interop.SHDocVw.1.1.dll in my programs folder?

Comment: @HalfEvil: Unless you want to write all the interop code yourself so that it ends up inside your application instead of a separate DLL.  You could also look at `ilmerge`.